# how to access instance of superclass when the instances come form another class?

Tags: java, inheritance

im trying to understand inheritance with this example but don't understand:i have a simple Point.java, Quadrilateral.java and Rectangle.java(subclass of Quadrilateral)

```
public class Quadrilateral{

private Point p1;
private Point p2;
private Point p3;
private Point p4;

public Quadrilateral(int x1, int y1,int x2, int y2, int x3,int y3, int x4, int y4){


     p1 = new Point(x1, y1);
     p2 = new Point(x2, y2);
     p3 = new Point(x3, y3);
     p4 = new Point(x4, y4);

}

public Point getP1(){
    return p1;
}

public Point getP2(){
    return p2;
}

public Point getP3(){
    return p3;
}

public Point getP4(){
    return p4;
```

}

then in the  subclass rectangle, points should be inherited in rectangle from Quadrilateral. if i want to access the points form rectangle class and maybe to know the Xposition, how i should do? if i write in rectangle class:  Point x = getP1().getX(); (getX() is in Point class) it doesn't work, compile error idenftifier expected. But even if i write just : Point x = getP1();//from the the superclass.Same error.Thank you

```
public class Rectangle extends Quadrilateral{



    public Rectangle(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int x3, int y3, int x4,int y4){
        super(x1,y1, x2,y2, x3,y3, x4,y4);

    }

   //how to access here point1, piont2 form superclass?
   //Point x = getP1(); doesn't work
```

Comment: `getP1()` is correct, `idenftifier expected` means something else in your java syntax is wrong. Can you show an example  that doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks zapl yes you are right getP1() is correct! i was saving modifications in a copy of the file not compliled so couldn't see the resutl of getP1() properly working...thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be making your `Point`s `protected` instead of `private` if you want to access them directly from a derived class.  Otherwise, you can simply use your `getPX()` to access them indirectly.

To access them in the derived class, you need to use a method.  For example:

```
public class Rectangle extends Quadrilateral{
    public Rectangle(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int x3, int y3, int x4,int y4){
        super(x1,y1, x2,y2, x3,y3, x4,y4);
    }

    //just an example:
    public Point getPoint1and2Sum() {
        return getP1().translate((int) getP2().getX(), (int) getP2().getY());
    }
}
```

Or, if you make your `Point` variables `protected`:

```
public class Rectangle extends Quadrilateral{
    public Rectangle(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int x3, int y3, int x4,int y4){
        super(x1,y1, x2,y2, x3,y3, x4,y4);
    }

    //just an example:
    public Point getPoint1and2Sum() {
        return p1.translate((int) p2.getX(), (int) p2.getY());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the different visibility types.

- `private`: only the class itself can access the private members
- default (no visibility descriptor): all classes in the same package can access the members
- `protected`: all classes in the same package and classes that extend the parent class can acces the protected members
- `public`: all classes can access the public members

So if you want to access the points `p1` - `p4` directly you'll have to declare them `protected`.